# Consultar obtener valor numeric en una variable

Tags: php, javascript, html

Buen dia tengo un problema para poder tomar el valor de una consulta $query
en PHP, la consulta es la siguiente

> $query = "SELECT SUM(Cast(importe as numeric(15,2))) as Total
>                       FROM cxpgastos
>                           Where acreedor = $acreedor";

Como le puedo hacer para pasarla a una variable y digamos

IF (resultquery > 15000.00)
     alert("ya supero su limite de credito");

Espero me puedan ayudar , y gracias.

Comment: Cual es el error que te está presentando?

Comment: No es error, no puedo realizar ese proceso para lanzar una alerta si el resultado de la query es mayor a 15000

Comment: Te refieres a que deseas ayuda de alguien desarrollando el código para la alerta?

Comment: Si, necesito tomar el valor de esa consulta, y si es mayor a 15000 me mande una alerta

Comment: Como está formulada la pregunta es imposible responder. Lo primero que necesitas es conectar a la base de datos, enviar esa consulta y obtener el resultado en una variable. Luego, si la consulta se realiza en el mismo archivo haces esto: `<script type="text/javascript">
   var resultadoBD = "<?php echo $resultadoBD; ?>"; alert(resultadoBD);
</script>` Si es en otro archivo, necesitas enviar una petición vía Ajax.